# Mover scrollview com botao react native

Tags: react-native

eu tenho um scrollview em react native, porem ele move apenas com toque do usuario. Qual metodo ou como eu poderia fazer para que ele movesse ao eu apertar em um botao? se quiserem o codigo do scrollview:

```
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} //desabilita a barra de rolagem
      scrollEventThrottle={10}//frequencia de atualizacao da posicao
      pagingEnabled
      onScroll={
        Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: this.animVal } } }]
        )
      }
    >
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Você pode utilizar o metodo `scrollTo` do react-native ou o `scrollToEnd`:

`scrollTo([y]: 300, object, [animated]: true)`

`scrollToEnd([options]: object)`

Caso tenha mais duvidas de uma olhada na documentação do react-native ela e sua amiga kkkk

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto

Vida longa e prospera